# How to redirect a user to an external login page and return to app and get the access token?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have been trying to get razor pages and components to work together for a simple redirect. The reason I have this problem is because components don't have access to `HttpContext`. It must also be said that I'm new to Blazor.

So basically, this is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. User accesses the app. He's not authorized so he's automatically redirected to the external auth server. The app includes a return url (eg. LoginCallback)
2. The auth server authenticates and redirects the user back to LoginCallback.
3. In LoginCallback I need to get the tokens. It must be noted that I'm using `OpenIdConnect` and `SaveTokens` is true. So the tokens should be stored in the cookie. In the page/component I need to do extra login-related stuff.
4. Once the extra login-related stuff is complete, the page/component will automatically redirect to the main app component, (eg. Dashboard)

So what I have at the moment is the following:

I left `_Host.cshtml` untouched. I changed `app.razor` as follows (snipped for brevity):

```
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @{
                        var returnUrl = navigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(navigationManager.Uri);
                        navigationManager.NavigateTo($"Login?redirectUri={returnUrl}", forceLoad: true);
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

I have a `login.cshtml` with the following code:

```
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    public async Task OnGet(string redirectUri)
    {
        await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties 
        { 
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            IsPersistent = true,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(15)
        });
    }
}
```

I have a `LoginCallback.razor` with the following code:

```
@layout LoginLayout
@page "/LoginCallback"

@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

@{
    navigationManager.NavigateTo("Dashboard", forceLoad: true);
}

@code {

}
```

I also have the main landing page `Home.razor` which should automatically redirect to the login and the code is:

```
@layout LoginLayout
@page "/"

@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
@inject IOptions<AppOptions> appOptions

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        @{
            navigationManager.NavigateTo("Dashboard", forceLoad: true);
        }
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        @{
            var baseUri = navigationManager.BaseUri;
            var returnUrl = $"Login?redirectUri={baseUri}{appOptions.Value.LoginCallback}";

            navigationManager.NavigateTo($"Login?redirectUri={returnUrl}", forceLoad: true);
        }
    </NotAuthorized>
 </AuthorizeView>
```

And finally I have `Dashboard.razor` with the following (markup removed):

```
@page "/Dashboard"
@attribute [Authorize]
```

With the above, the redirection from/to the app is working as expected. All I need is the following:

1. Get the tokens (access, id and refresh) in LoginCallback. I'd rather have a (scoped?) service that I can inject in both pages and components so I can retrieve the tokens easily.
2. Sometimes it happened that the Dashboard was briefly loaded before redirection occurred. This must be solved. Additional tests must be done.
3. Move `[Authorize]` to `_imports.razor` and add `[AllowAnonymous]` to `Home` and `Login`.

So how would I go about solving (1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ivan-Mark Debono, I've already answered your question... My code should work.

Here's a snapshot of my application before authentication [image: before authentication]

and after authentication

[image: after authentication].

Comment: @Ivan-Mark Debono, if your code still doesn't work, you can send me email, so I can send you a complete copy of my code. You may find my email in my profile.

Answer (score 0):

It boils down to that the only place you can access the HttpContext and so the tokens is in `_Hosts.cshtml`.

[Microsoft has docs how to go about this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0). But i'll include the main steps for completeness.

---

- In `_Hosts.cshtml`, retrieve the tokens and pass them into components world, via a parameter to `App.razor`:

```cs
@{
    var tokens = new InitialTokenState
    {
        AccessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token"),
        RefreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token")
    };
}
<app>
    <component type="typeof(App)" param-Tokens="tokens" />
</app>
```

- In `App.razor`, take the passed tokens and store them in a pre-registered (and injected) DI-service, that now can be injected and used thru out the app.

```cs
@inject MyTokenProvider TokenProvider
...
@code{
    [Parameter] public InitialTokenState Tokens { get; set; }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        TokenProvider.AccessToken = Tokens.AccessToken;
        TokenProvider.RefreshToken = Tokens.RefreshToken;
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

- For this to work, `services.AddHttpClient();` has to be registered in startup as well.

Comment: I tried this method and when I injected TokenProvider into other services, it was empty. I'll give it another try.

Comment: It looks like it's working when injecting into a component. I need to try it with a razor page.

Comment: I guess it depends on the order of everything being resolved, this provider will only have it's values set efter the App.razor has started, and that's why you have it available in the components, as those are loaded after the app. I believe this method is mostly for allowing access to the tokens from a component so it can call an API or so. But they are available to you in LoginCallback, correct?

Comment: Yes they are available. So at least I can access them in components.